# Descriptive statistics with some repeated observations for individuals

Tags: repeated-measures, stata, descriptive-statistics

Can anyone advise how to report descriptive statistics for clustered data? I am using `xtgee` command for logistic regression. But I am not sure how to report descriptive statistics, like N's for female and the outcome with a p-value.

I have 200 observations, but 150 unique individuals. I don't know how to tabulate this to report descriptive statistics.

Normally I would do:

```
tab var1 var2, chi2 // (giving me p value and frequencies)
```

But how would I conduct this while accounting for some ID's repeating?

Comment: Are you asking about how to present descriptive information conventionally in a 'Table 1' format (as is common in biomedical research), or are you asking for Stata code? (Your phrasing somewhat connotes the latter, which would be off topic here.)

Comment: @gung is there a statistical way to look at descriptive stats? while accounting for repeated measures? I dont want to count the same ID three times, if I am reporting race in the cohort.

Answer (score 1):

There are various commands like `xttab`, `xttrans, freq`, and `xtsum` and user-written `xtab`, but because the dependence of observations creates some statistical issues that depend on the details of that dependence, they are not as full-featured as the corresponding cross-sectional command. Thus there is no twoway `xttab, chi2`.

One solution is to rely on a simple longitudinal model and use margins or contrasts of margins like this:

```
. webuse nlswork, clear
(National Longitudinal Survey.  Young Women 14-26 years of age in 1968)

. xtgee union i.south, family(binomial) link(logit)

Iteration 1: tolerance = .04578874
Iteration 2: tolerance = .00097303
Iteration 3: tolerance = .00001415
Iteration 4: tolerance = 2.594e-07

GEE population-averaged model                   Number of obs     =     19,235
Group variable:                     idcode      Number of groups  =      4,150
Link:                                logit      Obs per group:
Family:                           binomial                    min =          1
Correlation:                  exchangeable                    avg =        4.6
                                                              max =         12
                                                Wald chi2(1)      =     139.98
Scale parameter:                         1      Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       union |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     1.south |  -.6540526   .0552808   -11.83   0.000    -.7624011   -.5457042
       _cons |  -1.027887   .0350255   -29.35   0.000    -1.096535   -.9592382
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins south

Adjusted predictions                            Number of obs     =     19,235
Model VCE    : Conventional

Expression   : Pr(union != 0), predict()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       south |
          0  |    .263494   .0067972    38.76   0.000     .2501717    .2768163
          1  |   .1568388    .006572    23.86   0.000     .1439579    .1697197
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins ar.south

Contrasts of adjusted predictions
Model VCE    : Conventional

Expression   : Pr(union != 0), predict()

------------------------------------------------
             |         df        chi2     P>chi2
-------------+----------------------------------
       south |          1      155.93     0.0000
------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |   Contrast   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
       south |
   (1 vs 0)  |  -.1066552   .0085412     -.1233956   -.0899147
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

This tells you that the p-value on the null that there's no unionization difference between southern and northern women is essentially zero.

The other solution is to collapse the data to a cross-section in a way that makes sense (say always union members,  never union members, union joiners, and union leavers) and use `tab, chi2`.